# How to copy only changed files with Publish over SSH

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm setting up Jenkins to build and then send  changed files to a remote server using SSH. However, using the Publish over SSH plugin, I can only find an option to specify files to send over. I only want to send over files that have changed on GitHub. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: have you ever found solution for that?

Comment: @T.Todua I ended up using rsync on the target server

Comment: the recent update/PR will add functionalty into `Publish over SSH`: https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/issues/65

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do might be outside of the scope of the Publish Over SSH plugin, but it is doable as a shell script.

You can run a command like this to get the files changed between the current commit and the last commit: `git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT`

Then using the results of that you can run a shell scp command.

You can do this in a pipeline or in a execute script post-build action.